# sticky element with JavaScript (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a sticky element with JavaScript. The plan is to get the initial position of my element. And when my `window.scrollY` is greater than the initial position, the element should become sticky. So far so good.

All works like expected, except that when `window.scrollY` is greater than `this.selectionInitialPosition` nothing happens.

Here is what I have:

computed property:

```
selectionInitialPosition() {
  return this.$refs.selectionHeader.getBoundingClientRect().top;
},
```

That returns a number, like expected: for example: 440

Here is my scrollHandler:

```
handleScrollEvent() {
  console.log('initial', this.selectionInitialPosition);
  console.log('scrollY', window.scrollY);
  console.log('?', window.scollY >= this.selectionInitialPosition);
  if (this.selectionInitialPosition < window.scollY) {
    this.isSticky = true;
  }
}
```

Take a look at `console.log('?', window.scollY >= this.selectionInitialPosition);`

And here is what I see in the Chrome console:

[image]

Please explain that to me. I'm going crazy here.

**EDIT:** As @jom pointed out, I had a typo in my if-statement.
It should be `window.scrollY >= this.selectionInitialPosition`

Comment: You have a typo in here: `console.log('?', window.scollY >= this.selectionInitialPosition);` as well as `this.selectionInitialPosition < window.scollY`...  "scollY"

Comment: Jesus Christ‍♂️ Thank you @jom

Comment: No problem. It happens. :)

Comment: @jom you should post it as an answer so it can be accepted :)